# bootstrap navigation li class dropdown active on parent

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Using bootstrap 3 when clicking on a child page in a dropdown menu it takes me to that page, however the top page in the navigation with li class dropdown does not show as active,  which makes sense as the child page is now active.

In order to guide the user and perhaps show them what area or tree in the navigation they are on, is it possible to also set the top page with an active class. I have seen methods where adding ID values to each page works but wanted a more automatic route for additional future pages.

Comment: Please post some code.

Comment: Even better, paste a JS Fiddle too.